# MVC3: Obtaining KeyAttribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, data-annotations

What is the best way to find which property has a `KeyAttribute` in provided Model (class)?

I tried with `DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider`; but `ModelMetadata` does not contain information about `KeyAttribute`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a model class named `MyModel`, you can find the properties with key attributes as follows.

```
var keyAttributedProps = typeof(MyModel).GetProperties()
   .Where(p => p.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(KeyAttribute), true).Length == 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Never tried, but i think you could use TypeDescriptor.GetProperties Method to get the dessired property. According with MSDN, it returns the collection of properties for a specified component using a specified array of attributes as a filter.

Check this link. I hope it helps:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3x9x2kh5.aspx#Y0